# \MakeUppercase does not uniformly capitalize in subsection titles

Tags: uppercase

[image]

I used the \MakeUppercase command to capitalize the subsection title, but there are some letters that are not capitalized synchronously.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{extbook}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,yhmath,mathrsfs,fontawesome}

\let\widering\relax
\usepackage{antpolt}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs,maybemath,xlop,polynom,slashbox}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tkz-tab,tkz-linknodes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,calc,intersections,angles,patterns,snakes,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri,shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage[hidelinks,unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm] {geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks,unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{currfile}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\renewcommand\thesection{\@arabic\c@section}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\@Alph\c@subsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\@arabic\c@subsubsection}
\makeatletter

\def\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[frame]
{\color{violet!80}\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont}
{\filright\normalsize\enspace \faGraduationCap~CHƯƠNG \Huge\thechapter\enspace}
{.5cm}
{\Huge\bfseries\filcenter\MakeUppercase}
\def\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\titleformat{\section}
{\fontfamily{put}\selectfont\color{magenta}\Large}
{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[shape=circle,draw,line width = 1pt,inner sep=1pt,fill=violet!10] (char){\Huge\textcolor{red}{\S\thesection}};}
{0em}
{\Huge\bfseries\filcenter\MakeUppercase}
\def\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont\large\bfseries\color{magenta}}
{
    \hspace*{-2.2ex}\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt,fill=violet!10] (char){\textcolor{red}{\thesubsection}};
}
{.1em}
{\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\def\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont\small\bfseries\color{magenta}}
{
    \hspace*{-2ex}\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]
    \node[shape=diamond,draw,inner sep=2pt,fill=violet!10] (char) {\textcolor{red}{\thesubsubsection}};
}
{-0.3em}
{\bfseries\MakeUppercase}


\begin{document}
\chapter{MỆNH ĐỀ - TẬP HỢP}
\section{TẬP HỢP}
\subsection{Tóm tắt lý thuyết}
\subsection{Các dạng toán và ví dụ}
\subsection{Bài tập tự luận}
\subsection{Câu hỏi trắc nghiệm khách quan}
\end{document}
```

`

Comment: unrelated but don't use the tabu package. It is broken and unmaintained.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, when I run your code with `pdflatex` I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GJ3q.png as result.

Comment: Do you get any errors or warnings in the log file?

Comment: @Marijn I can reproduce it with a current texlive. And a much shorter example is `\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[T5]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\MakeUppercase{Tóm tắt lý thuyết}
\end{document}`

Comment: @Marijn Before, I compile normally, but now when I compile, I have this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changes to the case changing system mean that new data is needed to support the T5 encoding used for Vietnamese. Until this is fixed in the release:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\group_begin:
  \bool_lazy_or:nnF
    { \sys_if_engine_luatex_p: }
    { \sys_if_engine_xetex_p: }
    {
      \cs_set_protected:Npn \__text_loop:nn #1#2
        {
          \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop:n {#1}
          \use:x
            {
              \__text_tmp:w
                \char_to_utfviii_bytes:n { "#1 }
                \char_to_utfviii_bytes:n { "#2 }
            }
          \__text_loop:nn
        }
      \cs_set_protected:Npn \__text_tmp:nnnnnn #1#2#3#4#5#6#7
        {
          \tl_const:cx
            {
              c__kernel_ #1 case_
              \char_generate:nn {#2} { 12 }
              \char_generate:nn {#3} { 12 }
              \tl_if_blank:nF {#4}
                { \char_generate:nn {#4} { 12 } }
              _tl
            }
            {
              \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN
                \exp_not:N \char_generate:nn {#5} { 13 }
              \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN
                \exp_not:N \char_generate:nn {#6} { 13 }
              \tl_if_blank:nF {#7}
                {
                  \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN
                    \exp_not:N \char_generate:nn {#7} { 13 }
                }
            }
        }
      \cs_set_protected:Npn \__text_tmp:w #1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8
        {
          \tl_const:cx
            {
              c__kernel_lowercase_
              \char_generate:nn {#1} { 12 }
              \char_generate:nn {#2} { 12 }
              \tl_if_blank:nF {#3}
                { \char_generate:nn {#3} { 12 } }
              _tl
            }
            {
              \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN
                \exp_not:N \char_generate:nn {#5} { 13 }
              \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN
                \exp_not:N \char_generate:nn {#6} { 13 }
              \tl_if_blank:nF {#7}
                {
                  \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN
                    \exp_not:N \char_generate:nn {#7} { 13 }
                }
            }
          \__text_tmp:nnnnnn { upper } {#5} {#6} {#7} {#1} {#2} {#3}
          \__text_tmp:nnnnnn { title } {#5} {#6} {#7} {#1} {#2} {#3}
        }
      \__text_loop:nn
        { 1EA0 } { 1EA1 }
        { 1EA2 } { 1EA3 }
        { 1EA4 } { 1EA5 }
        { 1EA6 } { 1EA7 }
        { 1EA8 } { 1EA9 }
        { 1EAA } { 1EAB }
        { 1EAC } { 1EAD }
        { 1EAE } { 1EAF }
        { 1EB0 } { 1EB1 }
        { 1EB2 } { 1EB3 }
        { 1EB4 } { 1EB5 }
        { 1EB6 } { 1EB7 }
        { 1EB8 } { 1EB9 }
        { 1EBA } { 1EBB }
        { 1EBC } { 1EBD }
        { 1EBE } { 1EBF }
        { 1EC0 } { 1EC1 }
        { 1EC2 } { 1EC3 }
        { 1EC4 } { 1EC5 }
        { 1EC6 } { 1EC7 }
        { 1EC8 } { 1EC9 }
        { 1ECA } { 1ECB }
        { 1ECC } { 1ECD }
        { 1ECE } { 1ECF }
        { 1ED0 } { 1ED1 }
        { 1ED2 } { 1ED3 }
        { 1ED4 } { 1ED5 }
        { 1ED6 } { 1ED7 }
        { 1ED8 } { 1ED9 }
        { 1EDA } { 1EDB }
        { 1EDC } { 1EDD }
        { 1EDE } { 1EDF }
        { 1EE0 } { 1EE1 }
        { 1EE2 } { 1EE3 }
        { 1EE4 } { 1EE5 }
        { 1EE6 } { 1EE7 }
        { 1EE8 } { 1EE9 }
        { 1EEA } { 1EEB }
        { 1EEC } { 1EED }
        { 1EEE } { 1EEF }
        { 01A0 } { 01A1 }
        { 01AF } { 01B0 }
        \q_recursion_tail ?
        \q_recursion_stop
  }
\group_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\MakeUppercase{Tóm tắt lý thuyết ư}
\end{document}
```

(The team are looking more generally at whether full Unicode support is needed even in pdfTeX: I suspect so.)

Comment: Thank you @Josep Wright. But symbol "ư" not not capitalized synchronously. https://imgur.com/nk0meUG

Comment: @CaoThànhThái I probably missed one: in the patch I've got ready for `expl3` I included that (it's in a different place in Unicode to the rest) - I'll edit my answer shortly